# Google maps v3 boundary hightlight

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, overlay

I've got a problem. In google maps research, when you search a province/region, the result appear with the province boundary hightlight. but when we do same localization in my code, I have same result excepte![enter image description here][1] no boundaries are hightlighted.
I tried maptype and mapstyle, but nothing works like the search on google maps.

Can someone help me?
Thanks
Eric

Answer (score 0):

This feature isn't exposed that I am aware of.

here is another question that explains how to accomplish this on your own.
[Highlighting borders of state and cities of US in Google Map API 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388590/highlighting-borders-of-state-and-cities-of-us-in-google-map-api-3)