# Country boundries using Google Map API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Is there anyway so I can get boundries of countries in polygon coordinates value using Google map API.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See this similar question:
[Google Maps V3: Draw German State Polygons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10874686/google-maps-v3-draw-german-state-polygons)

The Natural Earth Data Set in FusionTables has country polygons available in it.  You can style them as you like.

I used it to create this example:
http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTablesLayer_worldmap_linkto.html

Here is an example that uses a KmlLayer:
http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_world_countries_simple.html

**code snippet:**

```js
var kmlLayer = null;
var map = null;

function openIW(layerEvt) {
  if (layerEvt.row) {
    var content = layerEvt.row['admin'].value;
  } else if (layerEvt.featureData) {
    var content = layerEvt.featureData.name;
  }
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = "you clicked on:<br>" + content;
}

function initialize() {
  var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(36.4278, -15.9);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 0,
    center: chicago,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function() {
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = "";
  });


  kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/world_countries_kml.xml', {
    preserveViewport: true,
    suppressInfoWindows: true
  });
  kmlLayer.setMap(map);

  google.maps.event.addListener(kmlLayer, 'click', openIW);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="map_canvas" style="height:200px; width:300px;"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="info"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can your example be extended on two countries?

Comment: Sure. Not sure which example you are asking about, but that sounds like another question

Comment: Yes, it is. I am thinking if it is possible to visualise two countries by your code base and/or more countries.

Comment: [multiple country example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTables_MultiCountryBrowser.html?countries=Afghanistan,Albania,Algeria,United%20States%20of%20America,Brazil)

Comment: Do you have the code for preview? I would like to give a list for the drawing.

Comment: you mean `view-source`?  I don't understand what you mean by "I would like to give a list for the drawing" (but again, this is not a subject for comments, it is a new question).

Answer (score 10):

If you want more control over the displayed boundaries, I suggest using `google.maps.Data` layer instead of Fusion Tables. Fusion tables and Fusion Layer has their limitations, for example on the World Map in geocodezip's example you can see, that if you zoom out the map, the boundaries will collapse to points. With [Data Layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer) you can style specific boundaries, or hide them. `Fusion Layer` allows only conditional style changes. You can also add your own `click`, `mouseover`, `mouseout` listeners, you can change the boundary layer on the fly and more. Of course sometimes `Fusion Layer` is better alternative, for example if you have data contained in Fusion Tables, but if you want more control `Data Layer` is more than worthy alternative.

In my next working example I show World Country and US States boundaries rendered using `Data Layer`as example. You can of course use your own boundary files. If you don't have GeoJson version available (only Shapefiles or KML files), you can convert them to GeoJson using utilities like [mapshaper](https://github.com/mbloch/mapshaper) (simply run: `mapshaper -i myshp.shp -o format=geojson out.geo.json`)

```js
var map = null;
  var my_boundaries = {};
  var data_layer;
  var info_window;

  //initialize map on document ready
  $(document).ready(function(){
   var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.723080, -73.984340); //you can use any location as center on map startup
   var myOptions = {
    zoom: 2,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
    navigationControl: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   };
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
   google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(){
    if(info_window){
     info_window.setMap(null);
     info_window = null;
    }
   });
 
 $('#boundary_load_select').change(function(){
  if($(this).val()==1){
   loadBoundariesFromGeoJson("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/matej-pavla/Google-Maps-Examples/master/BoundariesExample/geojsons/world.countries.geo.json");
  }else{
   loadBoundariesFromGeoJson("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/matej-pavla/Google-Maps-Examples/master/BoundariesExample/geojsons/us.states.geo.json");
  }
 });
 loadBoundariesFromGeoJson("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/matej-pavla/Google-Maps-Examples/master/BoundariesExample/geojsons/world.countries.geo.json");
  });

  function initializeDataLayer(){
 if(data_layer){
  data_layer.forEach(function(feature) {
      data_layer.remove(feature);
  });
  data_layer = null;
 }
 data_layer = new google.maps.Data({map: map}); //initialize data layer which contains the boundaries. It's possible to have multiple data layers on one map
   data_layer.setStyle({ //using set style we can set styles for all boundaries at once
    fillColor: 'white',
    strokeWeight: 1,
    fillOpacity: 0.1
   });

   data_layer.addListener('click', function(e) { //we can listen for a boundary click and identify boundary based on e.feature.getProperty('boundary_id'); we set when adding boundary to data layer
    var boundary_id = e.feature.getProperty('boundary_id');
    var boundary_name = "NOT SET";
    if(boundary_id && my_boundaries[boundary_id] && my_boundaries[boundary_id].name) boundary_name = my_boundaries[boundary_id].name;
    if(info_window){
     info_window.setMap(null);
     info_window = null;
    }
    info_window = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
     content: '<div>You have clicked a boundary: <span style="color:red;">' + boundary_name + '</span></div>',
     size: new google.maps.Size(150,50),
     position: e.latLng, map: map
    });
   });
 
 data_layer.addListener('mouseover', function(e) {
  data_layer.overrideStyle(e.feature, {
   strokeWeight: 3,
   strokeColor: '#ff0000'
  });
 });
 
 data_layer.addListener('mouseout', function(e) {
  data_layer.overrideStyle(e.feature, {
   strokeWeight: 1,
   strokeColor: ''
  });
 });
  }

  function loadBoundariesFromGeoJson(geo_json_url){
 initializeDataLayer();
   $.getJSON(geo_json_url, function(data){
    if(data.type == "FeatureCollection"){ //we have a collection of boundaries in geojson format
     if(data.features){
      for(var i = 0; i < data.features.length; i++){
     var boundary_id = i + 1;
       var new_boundary = {};
       if(!data.features[i].properties) data.features[i].properties = {}; 
     data.features[i].properties.boundary_id = boundary_id; //we will use this id to identify boundary later when clicking on it
       data_layer.addGeoJson(data.features[i], {idPropertyName: 'boundary_id'});
     new_boundary.feature = data_layer.getFeatureById(boundary_id);
       if(data.features[i].properties.name) new_boundary.name = data.features[i].properties.name;
     if(data.features[i].properties.NAME) new_boundary.name = data.features[i].properties.NAME;
       my_boundaries[boundary_id] = new_boundary;
      }
     }
   if(my_boundaries[24]){ //just an example, that you can change styles of individual boundary
    data_layer.overrideStyle(my_boundaries[24].feature, {
     fillColor: '#0000FF',
     fillOpacity: 0.9
    });
   }
    }
   });
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("maps", "3",{other_params:"sensor=false"});
</script>
<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" >
 <select id="boundary_load_select">
  <option value="1">Load World Boundaries</option>
  <option value="2">Load US States Boundaries</option>
 </select>
 <div id="map_canvas" style="height:400px; width:500px;"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hey thank you dude i was searching for the url but your inner link worked for me thank you. Guys let me know if you want any help regarding plotting the country boundaries.

Comment: how can i get the cordinates of states of countries  other than US?

Comment: There is no uniform answer to that. For some countries you might not even be able to get them. For US, Australia and I also think NZ and CA you can find Census data where the boundaries are usually available. UK for example has Ordnance Survey. For some countries I couldn't find them at all for some they were paid. So you would have to google it.

Comment: how can i do it on zip level ?/

Comment: You start the same as country boundaries, but you have to find data for zip boundaries and that depends on country: for US you can find them (https://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/geo/shapefiles/index.php), for AU too, for some countries they are paid, for some I was unable to find any at all... So you have to search, there is no one place to get them all.. The problem though with zips is, that there's usually too many polygons for browser to handle. On tips how to do that check e.g. this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37167093/2661226

Comment: How did you get the country and state boundaries? - - Here a case where I would like find JSONs for these countries such that I could visualize the variables https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/108181/66725

Answer (score 0):

I guess by getting boundaries, you want to draw polygon on their borders. For that you must know the coordinates that will help to draw the polygon. I have did this thing only for US. I have all coordinates of all states. And I draw polygon on every state. That makes US highlighted.

You can see my this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388590/highlighting-borders-of-state-and-cities-of-us-in-google-map-api-3) for US solution. But for other countries, you must need to know the coordinates.

Comment: I want to draw polygon for Dublin but don't know coordinates, in that case how can I draw polygons?