# Fill specific region of Denmark - with polygons?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Im looking to "highlight" an area / specific region of the country Denmark, EXACTLY [like it's seen here](https://www.google.dk/maps/place/Capital+Region+of+Denmark/@55.8463921,11.789833,9z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x465386a5e163ca6f:0x300afc9aca85450!8m2!3d55.6751812!4d12.5493261):

I've read that drawing a fill (or stroke) can be done by drawing lots of polygons to the map, *example:*

```
var bermudaTriangleCoords = [
  new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262),
  new google.maps.LatLng(18.466465, -66.118292),
  new google.maps.LatLng(32.321384, -64.757370),
  new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262)
];    
var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
  paths: bermudaTriangleCoords,
  strokeColor: '#FF0000',
  strokeOpacity: 0.8,
  strokeWeight: 2,
  fillColor: '#FF0000',
  fillOpacity: 0.35
});
```

How would I go about drawing an exact fill like the initial above link? Can I somehow get the longitude and latitude coordinates from the above fill? Or do some Google Maps GUI exist where I can draw and get the coordinates?

[FIDDLE - Google maps demo](https://jsfiddle.net/h0w50keo/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Maps V3: Draw German State Polygons?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10874686/google-maps-v3-draw-german-state-polygons)

Comment: You can't fill Denmark with poygons, it's already full of yummy bacon 

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the coordinates from the google maps link you referenced. The polygon (let's call it boundary) is part of the google maps application, but there is no API call to retrieve it.

For some countries such data is available though, as geojson files, or shapefiles. For example [US Census organisation](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/cbf/cbf_state.html) provide such data for respective US states, UK has "Ordinance Survey" organisation which also provide such data, but not for free, also there are some commercial organisations (For example [here](http://spotzi.com/en/maps/#zipcodes) they have postal code boundaries for Denmark, but I cannot seem to find Denmark regions). So that's my first advice to you, try to search for something like: "Denmark regions boundaries shapefile" (if you know danish language, try in Danish, you might find some sites which I couldn't). Once you have the shapefile, you can use some convertor (e.g. [mapshaper](http://www.mapshaper.org)) to convert it to `geojson` format and then load the polygon on your map ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37092260/2661226) is an example on how to load world countries geojson to your map. You can load just one country/region, if your geojson contain coordinates just for that)

Alternatively, you can create your own very simple application, which allows you to draw on the map, and then print the coordinates to console. I have created a simple application for you, try to run it locally. After it loads, just click anywhere on the map to start drawing polygon and once you create it, watch javascript console for output of coordinates. You can then use the coordinates instead in your `bermudaTriangleCoords`):

```js
function init() {
 
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 8,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.697683, 11.59711)
 });

 var drawing_manager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
  map: map, 
  drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON
 });
 
 google.maps.event.addListener(drawing_manager, 'polygoncomplete', function(polygon) {
          console.log("Polygon vertices coordinates following:");
       polygon.getPath().forEach(function(el){
          console.log(el.toString());
       });
 });        
}
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=drawing&dummy=.js"></script>
<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" onload="init()">
  <div id="map" style="height:400px; width:500px;"></div>  
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this tool to draw the kml points, and then I would just replace the points with those in the example above. You can change the kml setting to javascript, and then just copy the coordinates out. 
http://www.birdtheme.org/useful/v3tool.html

It's really useful, hope it helps you.