# Create Google Map of the US, no markers, but each state would be its own marker (boundary)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, boundary

I'm new to Google Maps.

I'm searching for a way to use Google Maps to do the following:

1. Create a map of the United States, showing only boundaries of the states
2. No pin points / markers
3. The states would have a ‘mouse over’ effect to display content (desktop)
4. The states would have an ‘on click’ event to display content (mobile)

EXAMPLE:    http://maps.debt.com/ccus-geo-map.html (but without the pin points / markers and this map is not responsive)

Have any of you seen anything like this using Google Maps and if so, where? Is there a tutorial to perform this? The google docs were not helpful as markers were displayed and this is not the desired result.

Thanks,

Mitch

An example of the code I created below using the Google Documents, but this was not providing the desired results either ...

```
    function initialize() {

    var locations = [
    ['California (LOS ANGELES)', 34.0522, -118.2437, 1],
    ['Florida (MIAMI)', 25.7617, -80.1918, 2],
    ['Maine (HOULTON)', 46.1262, -67.8402, 3],
    ['Washington (CLALLAM)', 48.253517, -124.257798, 4]
    ];
    var mapProp = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.8282, -98.5795), /* exact center of the US */
        zoom: 4,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        /*
            ROADMAP (normal, default 2D map)
            SATELLITE (photographic map)
            HYBRID (photographic map + roads and city names)
            TERRAIN (map with mountains, rivers, etc.)
        */
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
    var marker, i;
    var markers = new Array();
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map
        });
        markers.push(marker);
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
            return function () {
                infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
    }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize)
```

Comment: you need to google KML, which defines the boundaries on a map, you need to find the kml data for each state and draw it to the map, then attach a click handler.. that should give you something to google.

Comment: ah, here it is: https://www.google.com/fusiontables/data?docid=17aT9Ud-YnGiXdXEJUyycH2ocUqreOeKGbzCkUw#map:id=3

Comment: https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=f7f805eb65eb4ab787a0a3e1116ca7e5

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this world map](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_world_countries_simple.html) but just the US (and probably bigger)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to load boundaries over your maps. The boundaries can be in KML format, geoJSON format, etc and depending on that you can use google maps [KML Layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml) or [Data Layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer#add_event_handlers) or even simple `google.maps.Polygon`s.

I have created an example for this using `Data Layer`, take a look at [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37092260/2661226) (In answer, run the javascript snippet and choose "LOAD US STATES BOUNDARIES" from the dropdown above the map), it solves very similar problem to yours.

The boundary files are publicly available from [US CENSUS](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-cart-boundary.html) (not sure about commercial licensing though, you will have to check that yourself) as `shapefile`s. More on how to convert `shapefile` to desired format, read the referenced answer.

**EDIT**

For the sake of being complete, here is working example with only US states boundaries and both hover and click listeners:

```js
var map = null;
var my_boundaries = {};
var data_layer;
var info_window;

//initialize map on document ready
$(document).ready(function(){
 var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(20.723080, -73.984340); //you can use any location as center on map startup
 var myOptions = {
  zoom: 2,
  center: latlng,
  mapTypeControl: true,
  mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
  navigationControl: true,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 };
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
 google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(){
  if(info_window){
   info_window.setMap(null);
   info_window = null;
  }
 });
 loadBoundariesFromGeoJson("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/matej-pavla/Google-Mapshttps://raw.githubusercontent.com/matej-pavla/Google-Maps-Examples/master/BoundariesExample/geojsons/us.states.geo.json");
});

function initializeDataLayer(){
 if(data_layer){
  data_layer.forEach(function(feature) {
   data_layer.remove(feature);
  });
  data_layer = null;
 }
 data_layer = new google.maps.Data({map: map}); //initialize data layer which contains the boundaries. It's possible to have multiple data layers on one map
 data_layer.setStyle({ //using set style we can set styles for all boundaries at once
  fillColor: 'white',
  strokeWeight: 1,
  fillOpacity: 0.1
 });

 data_layer.addListener('click', function(e) { //we can listen for a boundary click and identify boundary based on e.feature.getProperty('boundary_id'); we set when adding boundary to data layer
  var boundary_id = e.feature.getProperty('boundary_id');
  var boundary_name = "NOT SET";
  if(boundary_id && my_boundaries[boundary_id] && my_boundaries[boundary_id].name) boundary_name = my_boundaries[boundary_id].name;
  if(info_window){
   info_window.setMap(null);
   info_window = null;
  }
  info_window = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
   content: '<div>You have clicked a boundary: <span style="color:red;">' + boundary_name + '</span></div>',
   size: new google.maps.Size(150,50),
   position: e.latLng, map: map
  });
 });

 data_layer.addListener('mouseover', function(e) {
  data_layer.overrideStyle(e.feature, {
   strokeWeight: 3,
   strokeColor: '#ff0000'
  });
  var boundary_id = e.feature.getProperty('boundary_id');
  var boundary_name = "NOT SET";
  if(boundary_id && my_boundaries[boundary_id] && my_boundaries[boundary_id].name) boundary_name = my_boundaries[boundary_id].name;
  $('#bname').html(boundary_name);
 });

 data_layer.addListener('mouseout', function(e) {
  data_layer.overrideStyle(e.feature, {
   strokeWeight: 1,
   strokeColor: ''
  });
  $('#bname').html("");
 });
}

function loadBoundariesFromGeoJson(geo_json_url) {
 initializeDataLayer();
 $.getJSON(geo_json_url, function (data) {
  if (data.type == "FeatureCollection") { //we have a collection of boundaries in geojson format
   if (data.features) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.features.length; i++) {
     var boundary_id = i + 1;
     var new_boundary = {};
     if (!data.features[i].properties) data.features[i].properties = {};
     data.features[i].properties.boundary_id = boundary_id; //we will use this id to identify boundary later when clicking on it
     data_layer.addGeoJson(data.features[i], {idPropertyName: 'boundary_id'});
     new_boundary.feature = data_layer.getFeatureById(boundary_id);
     if (data.features[i].properties.name) new_boundary.name = data.features[i].properties.name;
     if (data.features[i].properties.NAME) new_boundary.name = data.features[i].properties.NAME;
     my_boundaries[boundary_id] = new_boundary;
    }
   }
  }
 });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("maps", "3",{other_params:"sensor=false"});
</script>
<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" >
     <div style="float:left;clear:both;height:15px;">
       You are hovering over: <span id="bname" style="font-weight:bold"></span></div>
 <div id="map_canvas" style="height:400px; width:500px;"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank You Matej P.

This looks like a solution that should work. I'll be looking further into this today.  I appreciate your timely response.

Mitch S.