# show pointers in map on city & state name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, google-maps, jquery

I am using some code in my view as,

```
<body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" class="span8" style="height:400px"></div>
</body>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBl7fhDpSzGAqljlW7OCJZBsq6oDlGeckw&sensor=false"></script>
<script src="<?php echo $BASE?>scripts/analytics/standard_prospects_physicallocations.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I am getting city & state name from the server side controller but I want to show pointers to those city. How can it be done? If you are having any reference for that then suggest me.

Comment: By that city and state name you can find it's latitude and longitude and you can then you can use latitude and longitude to show pointers on the map.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think we can mark state/city by their names, unless we have the related Lat/Longs.

If you have the set of lat/long for the border of a city or state, this can be marked as polygons.

I found, [**Google Geo Charts**](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart#Example) can help you marking areas.

Again, you can [***check this***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388590/highlighting-borders-of-state-and-cities-of-us-in-google-map-api-3) a s quick reference.

Answer (score 0):

[Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) would be the way to find out the lat/long from a city/state combo.

On the other hand. It would be a lot easier (cheaper on the round trip times and less requests (which are limited)) to retrieve the lat/longs from the same source as the city name/states.

Once you have the lat/longs, it just becomes a case of plotting markers as standard.

Comment: will you please give me function in jquery to fetch latlong value?

Comment: Sorry, I don't use jquery. js all the way here.