# Fetch Longitudes and Latitudes by walkthrough the MAP

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a question and I don't know that is feasible or not. I tried hard but I am not getting any idea. Actually what I am doing is I am collecting the data for doing a load test. For that I am collecting several address. I got some of the longitudes and latitudes from one of the website. Based on these longitudes and latitudes I generated the address by using the Google Places API. But I need more data but I don't have any geolocations.

Here my questions are

- Is there any way to get the address without mentioning the latitude and longitude by using google maps.?
- Is there any way to get the addresses by walk through the google maps.? Say for example, in the google maps if I click **San Jose, CA, United States** we can see a mark in the google maps (Mark represents boarders of that place). Is there any way to get all the addresses from that mark. Say for example, I will mention one of the geolocation and based on that I will move north side by slightly increasing the longitude and latitude and in the same way after some time I will move some other side etc.
- Is there any way to know the boarders of that place.?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to get the address without mentioning the latitude and longitude by using google maps.?

You can try out [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/start) to search based on the address. You can search for places there and return [Places](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/Place) that are likely to match the query.

> Is there any way to get the addresses by walk through the google maps.? Say for example, in the google maps if I click San Jose, CA, United States we can see a mark in the google maps (Mark represents boarders of that place). Is there any way to get all the addresses from that mark. Say for example, I will mention one of the geolocation and based on that I will move north side by slightly increasing the longitude and latitude and in the same way after some time I will move some other side etc.

I think you may be referring to the [oogle Maps Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) for this one. It can convert addresses to coordinates and vice-versa (reverse geocoding)

> Is there any way to know the boarders of that place.?

It seems to not be possible based on [this SO ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388590/highlighting-borders-of-state-and-cities-of-us-in-google-map-api-3). However it did provide an alternative solution that may be similar to what you want to do.

Hope this helps!